# add-apt-repository not adding packages?

Tags: package-management, ppa, repository

I want to install [SafeEyes](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes) on Ubuntu 17.10. Following the instructions from the official website.

First I execute `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slgobinath/safeeyes`, then `sudo apt update`. Among the output is: `Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slgobinath/safeeyes/ubuntu artful InRelease`.

However, if I subsequently try `sudo apt install safeeyes` I get a `Unable to locate package` error.

I have never had any trouble using external ppa's in the past (although I've done it only a couple of times) and I am not too familiar with how `apt` actually works, so the following is just a guess.
After googling a bit, I inspected `/var/lib/apt/lists/` and noticed there is only a single file corresponding to safeeyes: `ppa.launchpad.net_slgobinath_safeeyes_ubuntu_dists_artful_InRelease`, whereas other repositories also have some file `*_binary-amd64_Packages`. I searched the safeeyes file with grep for "Package: " but got nothing. I suppose this is the problem?

Is `add-apt-repository` failing to add the proper sources? I tried removing and re-adding the ppa, without success. I also checked the Issues tab on the safeeyes github page, but there were no other complaints, so I guess the problem is with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `add-apt-repositories` adds repositories to the list of sources, and never packages. 
Second, there are no packages for 17.10 in [ppa:slgobinath/safeeyes](https://launchpad.net/~slgobinath/+archive/ubuntu/safeeyes/+packages), which is why nothing gets installed.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe a stupid question, but is it not possible to install packages for 16.x on 17.10?

Comment: Usually, it's not a good idea, but I am not sure about this one.

Comment: @Scipio, in some cases it might work, in other case it won't work. It depends what the versions of the packages from the PPA need and if those things are compatible across the versions of Ubuntu. (For example, mkusb is a set of bash shellscripts, not using any compiled software, and is the same for several versions of Ubuntu, so you can use packages for 16.04.x on 17.10.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/a/992583/408767) explains why I couldn't use `apt install`, but in case anyone is googling safeeyes: you can actually install it via `pip3`, as is detailed in the [README](https://github.com/slgobinath/SafeEyes) if you scroll down to "Other Linux & Run from Source".

The program is then available through the command line (type `safeeyes -h` for instructions) and seems to work fine on 17.10.

Answer (score -1):

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~slgobinath/+archive/ubuntu/safeeyes) does not provide packages for Artful (17.10). Among currently supported Ubuntu releases, it only provides packages for Xenial (16.04).